# Highly skewed outcome variable in longitudinal data analysis?

Tags: time-series, distributions, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, skewness

I am making a model between predictor x and outcome y, which are both repeatedly measured over time. My outcome is highly skewed to the left (see picture), which I cannot correct with common transformation techniques. Because of this, I cannot run a mixed model analysis.

I was thinking of either dichotomising my variable (not preferable) or doing a generalized linear mixed model analysis (GLMM). However, I don't know if a GLMM is appropriate here.

Does anyone have any advice on how I can deal with this situation? I am a medical student with relatively limited statistical knowledge, and I use SPSS for my analysis.

[image: Distribution of outcome variable y]

Comment: You need to give us more context for your Q. This is too abstract, but a GLMM *might* well be appropriate. What is your skewed variable representing in the real world? Sample size? What is your ultimate goal? ...

Comment: The simplest model that gets the qualitative features right might be a mixture with, e.g. 40% distributed at a constant value of 1 and 60% distributed normally with mean 0.8 and standard deviation 0.1.